# Simple Website (Apache/PHP/MySQL + JavaScript)

Tags: php, javascript

I've been asked to create a fairly straightforward website for a friend. Essentially a user will log in, fill in a set of information, and submit it. This data will then need to written to a database (and read from/presented at a future point).

I'm not really a web developer (I do mostly Java/C++), but about 3 years ago I worked on a project where we created a site using WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL and PHP), with a bit of JavaScript/AJAX thrown in for good measure. I was going to use WAMP again, but am concerned that there might be better tools available now.

So, is the WAMP approach a good one for a straightforward site like this?

If so, what tools would you recommend to use for the development of PHP/Javascript?

Finally, I saw in one of the blog posts that Stack Overflow uses JQuery. Would it be worthwhile to use these libs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the website you're going to be building is hosted on a WAMP stack, then I'd say continue to use that; otherwise, you may wanna stick with Windows/IIS/PHP/MySQL or SQL Server. I always try to make sure my development environment mirrors production as much as possible.

Secondly, if the user is simply logging in, submitting a form, and is then considered to be done, then using Ajax might be overkill; however, if you're definitely going to be going to Ajax route, then I definitely recommend using a library. [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) are fine - either one makes Ajax ridiculously simple.

Finally, as far as suggested tools are concerned, find something that fits the bill for what you're developing. If this site is as simple as you claim it is, something like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) might be sufficient. Another option for the WAMP/LAMP stack is [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/). If you're going the Windows/IIS/SQL Server route, then use some of the [Microsoft Express](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/) tools.

I could be way off, but if you're building a really simple site, don't spend more time configuring shiny new tools for something that can be done with the existing toolbox you've got.

Comment: Yeah, I agree about AJAX being overkill for this particular site. Do you think JQuery/Prototype are useful for coding 'regular' JavaScript (without AJAX)?

Comment: I think that if you're going to be doing a lot of DOM manipulation, then I'd definitely roll with one of those. Each library smooths over inconsistencies across browsers so you don't have to worry about it. What kind of things are you planning to need to do using JavaScript?

Comment: I'd like the input mechanism to be interactive so that it responds intuituvely to user input. Also, I may need to get some server-side information so I'd like to keep the AJAX door open. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly agree with Tom on this one. If your experience previously, using a WAMP stack with some js thrown in was successful, then stick with that.

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) is a really good tool for most web development tasks, so that, or something a bit more weighty like [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/studio) would handle things nicely.

From your brief description of the requirements, I wouldn't suggest trying out something new like [Rails](http://www.rubyonrails.org/). It's nice but more work to learn than is really justified by the project.

Answer (score 0):

Using this as an opportunity to try out Ruby on Rails isn't bad. From you wording I assume that you have complete control on the environment. As an experience developer, it shouldn't be that difficult. The convention over configuration approach also simplifies the development.

I am afraid that I am not helping much!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Machform](http://www.appnitro.com/) for form creation.  It creates forms very easily and creates the database their info is stored in, and lets you email the results somewhere or access the db for further manipulation of the info.  I use it and I haved save so much time.  It's the best "form creator" I have ever tried.

I have also recently checked out a cms called [concrete5](http://www.concrete5.org/) that I found referenced elswhere on stackoverflow.  It has a form utility too.  Might be the fastest way to create something simple.